# Sphinx-4 with HTK model recognition performance

Tags: sphinx4, htk, handwriting-recognition

I have built an online handwriting recognition system using Sphinx-4 and HTK model together. When I use HTK's own decoding system recognition rate is 89%. However Sphinx-4 system with the same HTK model achieves slightly more than 50%.

Is this normal? Is there any room for improvement of Sphinx-4 accuracy with the HTK model?

Thanks

Additional information:

I built the Sphinx-4 system using the LatticeDemo example and followed the steps in [http://nshmyrev.blogspot.com.tr/2009/09/using-htk-models-in-sphinx4.html]. 
The config file of HTK system is like the following:

```
TARGETKIND = MFCC
TARGETRATE = 1
NUMCEPS = 12
ENORMALISE = F
NATURALBYTEORDER = TRUE
NONUMESCAPES = TRUE
```

The config.xml of Sphinx-4 is the following:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<!-- ******************************************************** -->
<!--  biship  configuration file                              -->
<!-- ******************************************************** -->

<config>        
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- frequently tuned properties                              -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** --> 
    <property name="absoluteBeamWidth"  value="0"/>
    <property name="relativeBeamWidth"  value="1E-50"/>
    <property name="absoluteWordBeamWidth" value="20"/>
    <property name="relativeWordBeamWidth" value="1E-60"/>
    <property name="wordInsertionProbability" value="1E-16"/>
    <property name="languageWeight" value="15"/>
    <property name="silenceInsertionProbability" value=".0"/>
    <property name="frontend" value="epFrontEnd"/>
    <property name="recognizer" value="recognizer"/>
    <property name="showCreations" value="false"/>

    
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- word recognizer configuration                            -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** --> 
    
    <component name="recognizer" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer">
        <property name="decoder" value="decoder"/>
        <propertylist name="monitors">
            <item>accuracyTracker </item>
            <item>speedTracker </item>
            <item>memoryTracker </item>
            <item>recognizerMonitor </item>
        </propertylist>
    </component>
    
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- The Decoder   configuration                              -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** --> 
    
    <component name="decoder" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.Decoder">
        <property name="searchManager" value="searchManager"/>  
        <property name=" " value="50"/> -->
    </component>
    
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- The Search Manager                                       -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** --> 
      
    <component name="searchManager" 
        type="edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager">
        <property name="logMath" value="logMath"/>
        <property name="linguist" value="flatLinguist"/>
        <property name="pruner" value="trivialPruner"/>
        <property name="scorer" value="threadedScorer"/>
        <property name="activeListFactory" value="activeList"/>
    </component>
    
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- The Active Lists                                         -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** --> 
        
    <component name="activeList" 
             type="edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.PartitionActiveListFactory">
        <property name="logMath" value="logMath"/>
        <property name="absoluteBeamWidth" value="${absoluteBeamWidth}"/>
        <property name="relativeBeamWidth" value="${relativeBeamWidth}"/>
    </component>
    
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- The Pruner                                               -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** --> 
    <component name="trivialPruner" 
                type="edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.pruner.SimplePruner"/>
    
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- TheScorer                                                -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** --> 
    <component name="threadedScorer" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.scorer.ThreadedAcousticScorer">
        <property name="frontend" value="${frontend}"/>
    </component>
    
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- The linguist  configuration                              -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    
 
    <component name="flatLinguist" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.flat.FlatLinguist">
        <property name="logMath" value="logMath"/>
        <property name="grammar" value="jsgfGrammar"/>
        <property name="acousticModel" value="wsj"/>
        <property name="wordInsertionProbability" value="${wordInsertionProbability}"/>
        <property name="languageWeight" value="${languageWeight}"/>
        <property name="unitManager" value="unitManager"/>
    </component>
    
   <component name="jsgfGrammar" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.jsgf.JSGFGrammar">
        <property name="grammarLocation" value="/home/efbilgin/HMM-Exp/HTK-9_Feats_5v/sphinx/"/>
        <property name="dictionary" value="dictionary"/>
        <property name="grammarName" value="word"/>
     <property name="logMath" value="logMath"/>
     <property name="addSilenceWords" value="false"/>
        <property name="addFillerWords" value="false"/>
    </component>
    
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- The Dictionary configuration                            -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <component name="dictionary" 
        type="edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.dictionary.FastDictionary">
        <property name="dictionaryPath" value="/home/efbilgin/HMM-Exp/HTK-9_Feats_5v/sphinx/7266.dic"/>
        <property name="fillerPath" value="home/efbilgin/HMM-Exp/HTK-9_Feats_5v/sphinx/7266.filler"/>
        <property name="addSilEndingPronunciation" value="false"/>
        <property name="wordReplacement" value="&lt;sil&gt;"/>
        <property name="allowMissingWords" value="true"/>
    </component>
        
    
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- The acoustic model configuration                         -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <component name="wsj"  type="edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.tiedstate.TiedStateAcousticModel">
        <property name="loader" value="wsjLoader"/>
        <property name="unitManager" value="unitManager"/>
    </component>

    <component name="wsjLoader" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.tiedstate.HTKLoader"> <!--Sphinx3Loader">-->
        <property name="logMath" value="logMath"/>
        <property name="unitManager" value="unitManager"/>
        <property name="modelDefinition" value="/home/efbilgin/HMM-Exp/UNIPEN_1000_10_Eq_J-1/hmm7/hmmdefs"/>
 
    </component>

    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- The unit manager configuration                           -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->

    <component name="unitManager" 
        type="edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager"/>

    
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- The frontend configuration                               -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    
    <component name="epFrontEnd" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.FrontEnd">
        <propertylist name="pipeline">
            <item>audioFileDataSource </item>
            <item>dataBlocker </item>
            <item>speechClassifier </item>
            <item>speechMarker </item>
            <item>nonSpeechDataFilter </item>
            <item>preemphasizer </item>
            <item>windower </item>
            <item>fft </item>
            <item>melFilterBank </item>
            <item>dct </item>
            <item>liveCMN </item>
            <item>featureExtraction </item>
            <item>streamHTKSource</item>
        </propertylist>
    </component>

 <component name="streamHTKSource" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.util.StreamHTKCepstrum">
 <property name="cepstrumLength" value="39"/>
 </component>

    <component name="audioFileDataSource" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.util.AudioFileDataSource"/>


    <component name="microphone" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.util.Microphone"> 
  <property name="closeBetweenUtterances" value="false"/>
    </component>

    <component name="dataBlocker" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.DataBlocker"/>

    <component name="speechClassifier" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.endpoint.SpeechClassifier">
        <property name="threshold" value="1"/>
    </component>
    
    <component name="nonSpeechDataFilter"  type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.endpoint.NonSpeechDataFilter"/>
    
    <component name="speechMarker" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.endpoint.SpeechMarker">
        <property name="speechTrailer" value="50"/>
    </component>
    
    <component name="preemphasizer" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.filter.Preemphasizer"/>
    
    <component name="windower" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.window.RaisedCosineWindower"/>
    
    <component name="fft" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.transform.DiscreteFourierTransform"/>
    
    <component name="melFilterBank" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.frequencywarp.MelFrequencyFilterBank"/>
    
    <component name="dct"  type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.transform.DiscreteCosineTransform"/>
    
    <component name="liveCMN"  type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.feature.LiveCMN"/>
    
    <component name="featureExtraction" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.feature.DeltasFeatureExtractor"/>
    
    <!-- ******************************************************* -->
    <!--  monitors                                               -->
    <!-- ******************************************************* -->
    
    <component name="accuracyTracker"  type="edu.cmu.sphinx.instrumentation.BestPathAccuracyTracker">
        <property name="recognizer" value="${recognizer}"/>
        <property name="showRawResults" value="false"/>
        <property name="showAlignedResults" value="false"/>
    </component>
    
    <component name="memoryTracker"  type="edu.cmu.sphinx.instrumentation.MemoryTracker">
        <property name="recognizer" value="${recognizer}"/>
 <property name="showDetails" value="false"/>
 <property name="showSummary" value="false"/>
    </component>
    
    <component name="speedTracker"  type="edu.cmu.sphinx.instrumentation.SpeedTracker">
        <property name="recognizer" value="${recognizer}"/>
        <property name="frontend" value="${frontend}"/>
 <property name="showDetails" value="false"/>
    </component>
    
    <component name="recognizerMonitor"  type="edu.cmu.sphinx.instrumentation.RecognizerMonitor">
        <property name="recognizer" value="${recognizer}"/>
        <propertylist name="allocatedMonitors">
            <item>configMonitor </item>
        </propertylist>
    </component>
    
    <component name="configMonitor"  type="edu.cmu.sphinx.instrumentation.ConfigMonitor">
        <property name="showConfig" value="false"/>
    </component>
    
    
    <!-- ******************************************************* -->
    <!--  Miscellaneous components                               -->
    <!-- ******************************************************* -->
    
    <component name="logMath" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.util.LogMath">
        <property name="logBase" value="1.0001"/>
        <property name="useAddTable" value="true"/>
    </component>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, performance issues are hard to detect, you can do several things about that:

1) Increase beam to make sure you do not have issues about pruning

2) Analyze word error. Do you have mostly insertions or deletions or what. Which words are most frequently confused

3) Sphinx4 is a speech recognizer, it for example adds fillers into grammar automatically. It also has background noise loop in latest versions. Make sure you disabled those. Sphinx4 HTK loader is expecting specific symbols in the model for example.

4) Make sure your feature extraction in s4 and HTK is identical.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For your suggestions: 1) Beam does not help in my case. 3) I have put some additional info to my original post. Since I am not from speech domain, I do not really know if I did the correct configuration for my system. It would be great if you could have a look at the config.xml. 4) I use the same features and the same .mfc files for both systems.Tragically, when I increase the lexicon size to 1000 words, Sphinx-4 system accuracy dropped almost to 0%. I suspect I miss some important detail in Sphinx part.

Comment: You did not provide number of insertions and deletions. One thing that is definitely wrong is wordInsertionPenalty which must be 0.2. Second thing is your frontend which should contain streamHTKSource only and nothing else.

Comment: Adding the wordInsertionPenalty value as 0.2 and cleaning up the frontend from unnecessary parts, I run another decoding process and here is the insertion, deletion etc. statistics which was missing previously "Accuracy: 1.912%   Errors: 2328  (Sub: 2308  Ins: 20  Del: 0)
   Words: 2353   Matches: 45    WER: 98.938%
   Sentences: 2353   Matches: 45   SentenceAcc: 1.912%"      I can see that something is wrong but cannot figure out what.  By the way this is an isolated word recognition task with a lexicon of 200 words.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev, Nikolay, hi, can you please take a look at my [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29989840/2545680) about sphinx-4?