# sphinx-4 aligner skips plain words like `you`, `in` and words with dashes - why?

Tags: speech-recognition, sphinx4

I'm trying to align simple text. Here are the links to text and audio files:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=48044768133759453374
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=99891199139563396901

Here is the configuration settings:

```
private static final String ACOUSTIC_MODEL_PATH =
        "resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us";
private static final String DICTIONARY_PATH =
        "resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict";
```

The output I get is the following (ellipsis are added by me):

```
- ï
- ¿in
  a                         [11250:11330]
  standard                  [11330:11920]
  shopping                  [11920:12440]
  centre                    [12440:13020]
- you
  can                       [13380:13730]
  ...
  shops                     [15170:15790]
- you
  can                       [16620:16890]
  buy                       [16890:17140]
  ...
  and                       [26920:27230]
  suits                     [27190:27220]
- thereâ€™s
  a                         [29160:29210]
  sportswear                [29210:29980]
  ...
  clothes                   [33330:33360]
- t-shirts
  shorts                    [35560:36320]
  jumpers                   [36630:37410]
  ...
  for                       [41860:42010]
```

As you can see for some reason it:

- didn't recognize `in` before the first `a`
- no timing for multiple instances of `you`
- didn't recognize `there's`, instead it identified it as `thereâ€™s`
- no timing for words with dashes, like `t-shirts`

Is there any way I can configure sphinx to provide timings for there occurrences?

Comment: files are not available under provided links

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev, sorry, updated links

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev, have you had a chance to take a look at the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments

> didn't recognize in before the first a

Your text file has BOM mark which is uknown to aligner. It is better to remove it before alignment

> didn't recognize there's, instead it identified it as thereâ€™s

Your text uses UTF-8 apostrophes which are unknown to aligner. You should better convert them to ASCII equivalent

> no timing for words with dashes, like t-shirts

Those words are missing in the dictionary. You can add them to the dictionary before alignment or specify g2p model to convert them to phonetics.

Comment: Greatly appreciate your help! I've removed BOM and changed apostrophes to ASCII, it now recognizes them. However, the issue with `you` remains - can you also take a look at this please? And do you recommend using text files encoded in ASCII with sphinx?

Comment: _You can add them to the dictionary before alignment or specify g2p model to convert them to phonetics._ - I've browsed the web but haven't found any existing g2p model that includes many words with dashes (like t-shirts), so I guess I'll try to add the word to a dictionary. The words are specified in this format: `women W IH M AH N`, what are these `W IH M AH N`? Where can I read about this syntax?

Comment: I think I've found what this syntax `W IH M AH N` mean - it's the `ARPABET (CMUdict)`, correct? Will it be enough to add a word to a dictionary so that sphinx can recognize it, or there are other steps I need to do? And questions I posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29989840/sphinx-4-aligner-skips-plain-words-like-you-in-and-words-with-dashes-why#comment48139787_30008830), can you take a look please?

Comment: CMUdict phoneset and syntax is covered at http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict. For aligner it is enough to add the word to the dictionary. g2p model for automatic conversion to phonemes is available in downloads http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/G2P%20Models/en_us_nostress.tar.gz/download

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll take a look at he links you provided. I understand I've asked a lot of questions already, but do you recommend using text files encoded in ASCII with sphinx? :)

Comment: Yes, sure, our aligner doesn't know how to process many utf-8 characters